# How to develop Mono 3 / .Net 4.5 projects with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, mono, monodevelop, .net-4.5

I need to migrate web application to Mono, and this application uses Entity Framework 4. Mono includes open sourced EF of 6th version, so I guess I must switch to EF 6 available on .Net 4.5 available on new Mono 3.

A problem is that when I installed Mono 3.0.3 and Mono Tools for VS 2010, nothing changed - there is still no way to select it as target.

By the way, I'm in doubt will it be possible to develop .Net 4.5 Mono project with VS 2010 if original .Net 4.5 is available only on Visual Studio 2012 I would be not too happy to migrate.

I tried also MonoDevelop, but it looks like it can target .Net 4.0 only, at least I found no options to target 4.5 and it has no EF model designer.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF6 works on both .NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 4.5. The difference is that async is not available on .NET Framework 4 so you will not be able to use EF async APIs.